# Como resolver solucionar erro de depuração em c#?

Tags: c#, visualbasic-powerpacks

Estou a executar o *release* do meu programa feito em C# numa outra máquina, e está a gerar erro de habilitação de depuração. Podem me ajudar com isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Experimente instalar na máquina [o Visual Basic Power Packs 10](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=145727&clcid=0x804).

[Aqui tem mais um link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/windows-forms/power-packs-controls), mais recente.

Comment: Gratos pela ajuda meu resultou.